# Is there a way to use rgb values with turtle's dot() function in python?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I have tried `colormode(255)` but that doesn't seem to be working. If it is not possible is there a work around for this?

Comment: Show us the code you tried, there's no reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: ```t.setpos(ax, ay)
t.colormode(255)
t.dot(6, 255, 0, 146)```

Comment: The RGB components need to be a tuple, rather than three separate parameters.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle as t

t.colormode(255)

tim = t.Turtle()

tim.hide()

tim.dot(30, (0,0,255))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle as t 
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
t.colormode(255)
timmy = Turtle()
t.dot(20,(254,235,105))
screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick
```